# Catalyst HTML::FormHandler DateTime

Tags: html, datetime, catalyst, html-formhandler

Hi I'm using the HTML::FormHandler in my Catalyst Project. I Want to you use the input field type DateTime-local as you can see here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_datetime-local

Can anybody tell me, if it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you set 'is_html5' in your form `has '+is_html5' => (default => 1);` you can use 'html5_type_attr' => 'datetime-local' in your field definition.